# Angular standalone component OnPush change detection strategy issue?

Tags: angular

I created a standalone component that looks like this:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { RouterLink } from '@angular/router';
import { ModeToggleService } from './mode-toggle.service';
import { ThemeMode } from './models';
import { ChangeDetectionStrategy } from '@angular/compiler';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-nav-bar',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [CommonModule, RouterLink],
  templateUrl: './nav-bar.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./nav-bar.component.scss'],
  changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush,
})
export class NavBarComponent {
  constructor(private modeService: ModeToggleService) {}

  mode$ = this.modeService.mode$;

  onThemeToggle(mode: ThemeMode) {
    this.modeService.toggleMode(mode);
  }
}
```

Everything worked fine until I added `changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush` . Now, when I hover over the ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush underlined error in VSCode , I see this note:

> changeDetection must be a member of ChangeDetectionStrategy enum from
> @angular/core Value is of type 'ChangeDetectionStrategy'.(-991010)

I can't figure out what is going wrong,  and I'd appreciate some help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, so the issue was that `ChangeDetectionStrategy`  should be imported from  `@angular/core`, and not from `@angular/compiler`, as it was automatically imported by VSCode for some reason.

Hopefully, this answer saves some debugging time for someone else.